# Turtle.py dot counter in figure

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm a starting programmer and I'm curious about how Python turtle counts dots in a filled figure. I tried to make a new figure that overlaps, but it doesn't complete my tests.  Is there any way to make it work?

```
import turtle as t
t.color('black','red')
scale = 100
t.speed(0)
t.begin_fill()
t.right(30)
for i in range(4):
    t.forward(5*scale)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(7*scale)
    t.right(90)
t.end_fill()
canvas = t.getcanvas()
counter = 0
for x in range(-120*scale, 120*scale, scale):
    for y in range(-120*scale, 120*scale, scale):
        item = canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x, y)
        if len(item) == 1 and item[0] == 4:
            counter +=1
print(counter)
t.done()
exit()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of initial issues with your code.  First, this doesn't make sense:

```
    item = canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x, y)
    if len(item) == 1 and item[0] == 4:
```

What `find_overlapping()` returns is a list of tkinter ids for the overlapping objects, so what does `item[0] == 4` mean?  You don't know the ids that tkinter is using so testing for `4` makes no sense:

Second, this code doesn't work correctly:

```
t.begin_fill()
t.right(30)
for i in range(4):
    t.forward(5*scale)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(7*scale)
    t.right(90)
t.end_fill()
```

You're drawing shape over itself and then trying to fill it, which fails.  The fix is to use `for i in range(2):` instead, as that's a geometric figure that can be filled.

Below is my rework of your code that I'm experimenting with, but I can't say that it's working as I don't understand your goal:

```
import turtle as t

scale = 100

t.color('black', 'red')
t.speed('fastest')
t.right(30)

t.begin_fill()
for _ in range(2):
    t.forward(5*scale)
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(7*scale)
    t.right(90)
t.end_fill()

canvas = t.getcanvas()

counter = 0

for x in range(-120*scale, 120*scale, scale):
    for y in range(-120*scale, 120*scale, scale):
        ids = canvas.find_overlapping(x, y, x, y)
        if len(ids) > 0:
            counter += 1

print(counter)
t.done()
```